# How do I use a calculated column within a Scalar function in a CTE in a Stored procedure..

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok, the title is probably confusing.

I need to use a case statement to calculate the amount of tax to deduct offa value.

This reduced value will be used in a Scalar function to calculate another value in a CTE in a Stored procedure..

How can I re-use this calculated column inside the scalar function?? I have tried the following.

```
paidminusIPT = case when country = "ireland" then (paid - 1) else paid end,
dbo.fnEarnedPrem(a,b,c,d,paidminusipt,e,f)
```

please note, this isn't the exact code, just a quick reference..

Is this possible to do?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use full expression instead of just column name:

```
paidminusIPT = case when country = "ireland" then (paid - 1) else paid end,
dbo.fnEarnedPrem(a,b,c,d,case when country = "ireland" then (paid - 1) else paid end,e,f)
```

or use CTE

```
;WITH C as(
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,paidminusIPT = case when country = "ireland" then (paid - 1) else paid end FROM SomeTable)
Select *,dbo.fnEarnedPrem(a,b,c,d,paidminusipt,e,f) FROM C
```

Comment: so basically you cant?? ok, i'll just have to do it the long way!! cheers!